# What to do with massively upvoted incorrect answers?

Tags: discussion

[How can I reformat my SD card to use it normally again?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1446/how-can-i-reformat-my-sd-card-to-use-it-normally-again)

The accepted, top-voted answer is patently wrong. All it does for Windows and Mac is wiping the tiny FAT partition of the SD card, leaving the Ext3 partition untouched, quite contrary to what the asker requested. Still, with 20 upvotes it's unlikely to be overpassed by the next (correct) answer which, while more complex, achieves the goal.

If the majority votes that Earth is flat... what should we do?

Comment: As it was my answer I have deleted it. As the answer was accepted it implies that the question may have solved the original users problem. If not the current wording.

Comment: @SteveRobillard: The problem is it *looks* like it solves the problem, leaving a blank partition. You need to look harder at the results to see it does not reclaim the Linux partition.

Comment: Here's the same question on StackOverflow Meta:

http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8879

Comment: Yea I was also questioning the answer there as that is NOT how to fully format an SD card. But the other part of the answer does do. People will go and try all the solutions. There are NO downvotes so nobody found it a problem? People must realise the during format what is going and ans search another question, ie how to resize partition?

Answer (score 6):

Taking from Jivings's comment above (since it's worth posting as an answer), from [How to deal with upvoted yet clearly wrong answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8897) on Stack Overflow:

> - Leave a comment
> - Downvote the wrong answer
> - Provide or upvote a correct answer
> - If it is really, *really* wrong (as in dangerously worng, like *'delete C:\NTLDR in order to improve computer performance'*), flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 3):

Just comment on it saying it's wrong and downvote it yourself. Flag it as:"Not an answer". I don't think there is much more to do actually.